# String comparison in python words ending with

Tags: python

I have a set of words as follows:

```
['Hey, how are you?\n','My name is Mathews.\n','I hate vegetables\n','French fries came out soggy\n']
```

In the above sentences i need to identify all sentences ending with `?` or `.` or 'gy'. and print the final word.

My approach is as follows:

```
# words will contain the string i have pasted above.
word = [w for w in words if re.search('(?|.|gy)$', w)]
for i in word:
    print i
```

The result i get is:

> Hey, how are you?
>
> My name is Mathews.
>
> I hate vegetables
>
> French fries came out soggy

The expected result is:

> you?
>
> Mathews.
>
> soggy

Comment: Are you looking to print the sentences or the Words at the end of the sentences?

Comment: Only the words, not the sentence

Comment: By the way, you don't have a set of words, you have a list of strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method.

```
>>> for line in testList:
        for word in line.split():
            if word.endswith(('?', '.', 'gy')) :
                print word
```

Output:

```
you?
Mathews.
soggy
```

Comment: You don't need to call `strip()`, because `split()` without separator trims leading, trailing spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Use [endswith](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.endswith) with a tuple.

```
lines = ['Hey, how are you?\n','My name is Mathews.\n','I hate vegetables\n','French fries came out soggy\n']
for line in lines:
    for word in line.split():
        if word.endswith(('?', '.', 'gy')):
            print word
```

---

Regular expression alternative:

```
import re

lines = ['Hey, how are you?\n','My name is Mathews.\n','I hate vegetables\n','French fries came out soggy\n']
for line in lines:
    for word in re.findall(r'\w+(?:\?|\.|gy\b)', line):
        print word
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close.

You just need to escape the special characters (`?` and `.`) in the pattern:

```
re.search(r'(\?|\.|gy)$', w)
```

[More details in the documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: BTWm what is the `r` ?

Comment: @sharonHwk, Strings with leading `r` is called raw strings. Raw strings escape back slash.

Comment: @sharonHwk It's a raw string. The documentation opens with [more details](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).